# Buffer Overflow calling two functions with parameters

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am learning about BOF, and I understood how it can be used for calling function with argument(s), but what about calling two functions each with arguments.
For calling one function with argument(s): first we input the address of the function in the location of EIP, then the return address, then the argument(s).
In this code I want to call ***secret*** function by calling ***function1*** then ***function2***, how can I do that ???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function1(int, int);
void function2(int);
void secret();


void function1(int var1, int var2) {
    if(var1 == 0x123456) {
        function2(var2);
    }
}

void function2(int var) {
    if(var == 0xabcdef) {
        secret();
    }
}

void secret() {
    printf("%s\n", "Correct");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buff[64];
  strcpy(buff, argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want to have BOF itself cause two function calls? Isn't it enough to have `function1()` call `function2()`?

Comment: function1() calls function2() itself but I have to insert the correct position for arguments and addess for function1() as well as for function2()

Comment: I dont understand how this causes Buffer Overflow, i dont see any cyclic or recursive calls. I am i missing something?

Comment: @sravs `strcpy(buff, argv[1]);` can write beyond allocated memory.

Comment: @MikeCAT you are right, I just overlooked it, but if that's the case then why write all those functions, i mean BOF objective achieved with `strcpy` itself

Comment: `strcpy(buff, argv[1])` is vulnerable to BOF by overwriting EIP value.

Comment: @sravs we can call `secret` function directly but I want to learn if it is possible to call two functions with arguments of each, because there are challenges in the internet depends on this kind of exploitation, that is the aim of my question.

Comment: `function1` already calls `function2` given the correct parameters, so would it be accurate to say that you just want to call `function1(0x123456, 0xabcdef)`?